# TSQL : Sum of count of distinct rows per day within a specified time period

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I am trying to get the customer count per day,
The bill number is identical in POS machines.

**TSQL query**

```
 SELECT sum(tot) as Customer_Count
    FROM 
       (select count(distinct (slip_no)) as tot 
        from rem_upload r
        where  (r.location_id like '001') and (r.tran_type <>'Z' and r.tran_type <> 'X') and (r.tran_date >= '2014-01-02' and r.tran_date  <= '2014-01-03') 
        group by mech_no)   
as C_count
```

**OutPut:**

```
Customer_Count
379
```

I need to get the total customer count per day for a specified time period.

Now what I get in my output is the total customer count of a given period.

Thank you,

Comment: try adding more filter per day and your time range on where statement

Comment: You can `GROUP BY r.tran_date` inside your source subquery, afterwards include `tran_date` as a column in your resultset and `GROUP BY tran_date` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along those lines:

```
 SELECT C_count.tran_date
        ,SUM(C_count.tot) as Customer_Count
 FROM 
       (SELECT r.tran_date
       ,COUNT(distinct (slip_no)) as tot 
        FROM rem_upload r
        WHERE  (r.location_id like '001') and (r.tran_type <>'Z' and r.tran_type <> 'X') and (r.tran_date >= '2014-01-02' and r.tran_date  <= '2014-01-03') 
        GROUP BY r.mech_no
                 ,r.tran_date)as C_count
  GROUP BY tran_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested..but the idea is something like this.

Try replace the following:

`<your_specified_date>` by your custom date

`r.<timestamp_column>` if you have a timestamp column type

`<your_specified_time_range>` by your custom time.

```
SELECT sum(tot) as Customer_Count
FROM 
   (select count(distinct (slip_no)) as tot 
    from rem_upload r
    where (r.location_id like '001') 
      and (r.tran_type <>'Z' and r.tran_type <> 'X') 
      and (r.tran_date >= '2014-01-02' and r.tran_date  <= '2014-01-03')
      and r.tran_date = <your_specified_date>
      and r.<timestamp_column> = <your_specified_time_range>
    group by mech_no)   
as C_count
```